# different between *p[num] and (*p)num

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

In my C program book, I meet the question about `(*p)[num2]`
there is a 2 dimension array named `a[num1][num2]` and a `(*p)[num2]`
next,in the statement

```
for(p=&a[0];p<&a[num1];p++)
(*p)[i]=0;
```

that statement will make the 2 dimension array's i column assign 0
but i don't understand why `(*p)[num2]` point to `a`'s row,I think create `*p` and `p=&a[num1]` can do that,too.
and,why `p++` point to next row but not the next value behind `a[num][i]`

why?,i have understand the difference between `*p[3]` and `(*p)[3]`
I think *p could point to an array(first address) why used (*p)[num] to point array.

Comment: parenthesis first, like in math. If you check operator precedence table, operator `[]`  comes before unary `*`

Comment: `p=&a[0];p<&a[num1]...` is a fancy way of saying `p=a,end=p+num1;p<end...`.

Comment: Take a look at the definition of `p`. Then you'll see why `p++` behaves as it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start from providing a useful quote from the C standard relative to arrays and implicit conversions (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)"

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, or the unary &
> operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an
> expression that has type "array of type" is converted to an expression
> with type "pointer to type" that points to the initial element of the
> array object** and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register
> storage class, the behavior is undefined.

So if for example you have an array like that

```
int a[num1][num2];
```

then used in expressions with rare exceptions mentioned in the quote it is implicitly converted to a pointer to its initial element.

Elements of the two-dimensional array `a` are in turn arrays of the type `int[num2]`. A pointer to the element type of the array has type `int ( * )[num2]`. You may declare a corresponding pointer the following way

```
int ( *p )[num2] = a;
```

that is the same as

```
int ( *p )[num2] = &a[0];
```

Now the pointer `p` points to the first "row" of the two-dimensional array `a`. After incresing it using the prefix increment operator `++p` or postfix increment operator `p++` it will point to the next (second) element (row) of the type `int[num2]` of the array `a`. Dereferencing the pointer like `*p` you will get the one-dimensional array (row) of the type `int[num2]` pointed to by the pointer. And to apply to the resulted expression the subscript operator like `( *p )[i]` you will get the `i-th` element of the current row of the array `a`.

On the other hand, if you have

```
int ( *p )[num2] = a;
```

then the expression `p + num1` will point to the memory after the last element (one-dimensional array of the type `int[num2]`) of the array `a`. The expression `p + num1` is equivalent to the expression `a + num1` (due to the implicit conversion of the array `a` to a pointer to its initial element)  that in turn is equivalent to the expression `&a[num1]`.  According to the last expression there is written in the C Standard (6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators)

> 3 The unary & operator yields the address of its operand. If the
> operand has type "type", the result has type "pointer to type". If the
> operand is the result of a unary * operator, neither that operator nor
> the & operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were omitted,
> except that the constraints on the operators still apply and the
> result is not an lvalue. **Similarly, if the operand is the result of
> a [] operator, neither the & operator nor the unary * that is implied
> by the [] is evaluated and the result is as if the & operator were
> removed and the [] operator were changed to a+ operator.** Otherwise,
> the result is a pointer to the object or function designated by its
> operand.

So as it follows from the quote the expression `&a[num1]` is equivalent to the expression `a + num1`.

Thus this for loop

```
for ( p = &a[0]; p < &a[num1]; p++ )
    ( *p )[i] = 0;
```

may be rewritten like

```
for ( p = a; p < a + num1; p++ )
    ( *p )[i] = 0;
```

As for the subscript operator then (the C Standard, 6.5.2.1 Array subscripting):

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
> is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
> definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical
> to (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
> binary+ operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to
> the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer, E1[E2]
> designates the E2 -th element of E1 (counting from zero).

Thus this expression statement in the body of the for loop

```
( *p )[i] = 0;
```

may be also rewritten like

```
*( *( p + 0 ) + i ) = 0;
```

or like

```
*( *p + i ) = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

The definitions means

```
TYPE a[num1][num2];  // Array of array of TYPE, i.e.
                     // an array with num1 elements where each element
                     // is an array with num2 elements of type TYPE

TYPE (*p)[num2];     // Pointer to array of TYPE, i.e.
                     // a pointer to an array with num2 elements of type TYPE
```

so

```
p=&a[0];
```

will give you a pointer to the first "inner" array of `a`. For 2D this is often called the "first row".

Then

```
p++;
```

will give you a pointer to the second "inner" array of `a`. In other words a pointer to the second row. So incrementing `p` will make `p` a pointer to the next row.

Dereferencing `p`, i.e. `*p` will give you the array (i.e. row) that `p` is currently pointing at. In most situations the array the will converted to a pointer to the first element, i.e. a pointer of type TYPE. As if you did:

```
TYPE* row = *p;
```

Now you can access the elements of the row using `row[i]`.

Like

```
TYPE* row = *p;
TYPE value = row[i];
```

As a single statement this is the same as `(*p)[i]`.

The parentheses are needed due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Without parentheses like `*p[i]` the expression is like `*(p[i])` which rather means: Get a pointer to the i'th row and read the first element of that row.

Example:

```
  int a[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
  int (*p)[2] = &a[0];
  
  // Print all elements in the row p point to (here row 0)
  for (int i=0; i < 2; i++) {
    printf("%d ", (*p)[i]);
  }

  puts("\n-----------------------");

  // Print the first element of all rows
  for (int i=0; i < 2; i++) {
    printf("%d ", *p[i]);
  }
```

Output:

```
1 2 
-----------------------
1 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `p` points to not only the two-dimensional array `a`, but also the one-dimensional array of `a[0]`, `a[1]`, etc. So, `p++` points to the first position of the next row of `a`.